# Query for count of distinct values in a rolling date range and country

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, grouping, distinct-values

Good evening dear Stack overflow community.
This is my first question here.

I have the following issue: I need a query to count distinct values in a rolling date range (3 days) for each country.

I have done some research and found the following discussion here [1]: [Query for count of distinct values in a rolling date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544182/query-for-count-of-distinct-values-in-a-rolling-date-range).

For the problem I face I need grouping not only by date, but also by country. Please consider the following input table:

| Date | Country | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/12 | DE | de1@example.com |
| 1/1/12 | FRA | fra1@example.com |
| 1/1/12 | SPA | spa1@example.com |
| 1/2/12 | DE | de1@example.com |
| 1/2/12 | DE | de2@example.com |
| 1/3/12 | SPA | spa1@example.com |
| 1/3/12 | SPA | spa2@example.com |
| 1/3/12 | FRA | fra2@example.com |
| 1/4/12 | SPA | spa1@example.com |
| 1/4/12 | FRA | fra2@example.com |
| 1/4/12 | FRA | fra3@example.com |
| 1/4/12 | SPA | spa3@example.com |

The expect outcome with counted distinct emails will be the following:

| Date | Country | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/12 | DE | 1 |
| 1/1/12 | FRA | 1 |
| 1/1/12 | SPA | 1 |
| 1/2/12 | DE | 2 |
| 1/2/12 | FRA | 1 |
| 1/2/12 | SPA | 1 |
| 1/3/12 | SPA | 2 |
| 1/3/12 | DE | 2 |
| 1/3/12 | FRA | 2 |
| 1/4/12 | SPA | 3 |
| 1/4/12 | FRA | 2 |
| 1/4/12 | DE | 2 |

I was trying to modify the solution suggested in the above-mentioned discussion and modify the following by adding country in selected columns and in grouping.

```
SELECT date
     ,(SELECT count(DISTINCT email)
       FROM   tbl
       WHERE  date BETWEEN g.date - 2 AND g.date
      ) AS dist_emails
FROM  (SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2012-01-01'
                            , timestamp '2012-01-06'
                            , interval  '1 day')::date) AS g(date)
```

Unfortunately the updated query does not work, as country is not recognised and it errors.

```
SELECT date, country,
         ,(SELECT count(DISTINCT email)
           FROM   tbl
           WHERE  date BETWEEN g.date - 2 AND g.date
          ) AS dist_emails
    FROM  (SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2012-01-01'
                                , timestamp '2012-01-06'
                                , interval  '1 day')::date) AS g(date)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Will be very grateful for your advice and sharing your expertise on  the ways this can be fixed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks and sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting with your SQL

Comment: SQL compilation error: error line1 at position 17 invalid identifier 'country'. The issue happens in Snowflake. Unfortunately I can not edit the question and add the relevant tag. Admins could you please help with this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `country` doesn't exist is that we can only `SELECT` columns from the tables that are in a `FROM` section of a query. The nested subquery selects `from tbl` but that is not available to the main, outer query, which only selects from the generated table `g`.  `g` only has a `date` column, so that's the only column the outer query can select on directly.

Another issue with the query is that the `COUNT` is not factoring in countries.

For this I'd use basic join to query every row for every date range, then do a `count distinct` for every date + country. You can use an `INNER` join to remove days that have no entries or `LEFT OUTER` to return rows of `{date}, nil,nil` if there are no entries for that date range. Something like:

```
SELECT g.date
     , tbl.country
     , COUNT(DISTINCT(tbl.email))
    FROM  (SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2012-01-01'
                                , timestamp '2012-01-06'
                                , interval  '1 day')::date) AS g(date)
    INNER JOIN tbl ON (tbl.date BETWEEN g.date - 2 AND g.date)

GROUP BY 1,2
```